# error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly when running Xamarin iOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin, gdal, aot

I have a Xamarin .iOS project, that is using GDAL(libgdal.a) and PROJ(libproj.a) files.

I m trying to executing the iOS project and getting following build error:

```
Target(s) <ProjectPath>/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/registrar.o must be rebuilt.
    <Path>/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -Wno-receiver-forward-class -Wno-objc-missing-super-calls -Wno-unguarded-availability-new -stdlib=libc++ -gdwarf-2 -std=c++14 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.10.0.4/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/include -isysroot <Path>/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk -Qunused-arguments -miphoneos-version-min=14.4 -arch arm64 -c -o “/<Path>/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/registrar.o" -x objective-c++ -D DEBUG “<Path>/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.m"
    MTOUCH : error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/<username>/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS.exe'
```

Note:

my visual studio has following version

Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.8.8 (build 12)
Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)
Mono Framework MDK Runtime:Mono 6.12.0.113 (2020-02/4fdfb5b1fd5) (64-bit)
NuGet Version: 5.8.0.6860

.NET Core SDK
SDK Versions:5.0.103
.NET Core Runtime 5.0.3
3.1.12
.NET Core 3.1 SDK: 3.1.406

Xcode 12.4 (17801)
Xamarin.Mac : Version: 7.4.0.4 (Visual Studio Community)
Xamarin.iOS Version: 14.10.0.4 (Visual Studio Community)
Operating System Mac OS X 10.16.0
Darwin 20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0

Please also find part of build log

```
MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/MonoTouch.NUnitLite.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/MonoTouch.NUnitLite.dll.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/MonoTouch.NUnitLite.dll"
    AOT : Unknown argument 'GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/MonoTouch.NUnitLite.aotdata.arm64'.
    AOT Compilation exited with code 1, command:
    MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,soft-debug,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS.exe.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS.exe"
    AOT : Unknown argument 'GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS.aotdata.arm64'.
    AOT Compilation exited with code 1, command:
    MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Xml.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Xml.dll.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/System.Xml.dll"
    AOT : Unknown argument 'GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Xml.aotdata.arm64'.
    AOT Compilation exited with code 1, command:
    MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.dll.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/System.dll"
    AOT : Unknown argument 'GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.aotdata.arm64'.
    AOT Compilation exited with code 1, command:
    MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/Xamarin.iOS.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/Xamarin.iOS.dll.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/Xamarin.iOS.dll"
    AOT : Unknown argument 'GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/Xamarin.iOS.aotdata.arm64'.
    AOT Compilation exited with code 1, command:
    MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/mscorlib.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/mscorlib.dll.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/mscorlib.dll"
    AOT : Unknown argument 'GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/mscorlib.aotdata.arm64'.
    MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll"
    MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/OSGeo.GDAL.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,soft-debug,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/OSGeo.GDAL.dll.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/OSGeo.GDAL.dll"
    Generating static registrar for MonoTouch.Dialog-1, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
    /Users/Dev/Downloads/XCode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -gdwarf-2 -std=c++14 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/include -isysroot /Users/Dev/Downloads/XCode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk -Qunused-arguments -miphoneos-version-min=14.5 -arch arm64 -c -o "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/main.o" -x objective-c++ -D MONOTOUCH -D DEBUG "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/main.m"
    Generating static registrar for OSGeo.GDAL, Version=1.0.7917.4345, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    AOT Compilation exited with code 1, command:
    MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll"
    AOT : Unknown argument 'GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.aotdata.arm64'.
    AOT Compilation exited with code 1, command:
    MONO_PATH='/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build' /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt -O=-float32 "--aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/OSGeo.GDAL.aotdata.arm64,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,interp,full,soft-debug,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/OSGeo.GDAL.dll.s" "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/OSGeo.GDAL.dll"
    AOT : Unknown argument 'GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/OSGeo.GDAL.aotdata.arm64'.
    File '/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.m' does not exist, creating it.
    File '/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.h' does not exist, creating it.
    Target(s) /Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/registrar.o must be rebuilt.
    /Users/Dev/Downloads/XCode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -Wno-receiver-forward-class -Wno-objc-missing-super-calls -Wno-unguarded-availability-new -stdlib=libc++ -gdwarf-2 -std=c++14 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.20.0.24/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/include -isysroot /Users/Dev/Downloads/XCode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk -Qunused-arguments -miphoneos-version-min=14.5 -arch arm64 -c -o "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/registrar.o" -x objective-c++ -D DEBUG "/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.m"
    MTOUCH : error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/Dev/Desktop/test proj/XamarinGeoTest/Lib/OSGeo,GDAL.Xamarin/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-14.7.1/mtouch-cache/3-Build/OSGeo.GDAL.Test.iOS.exe'
```

Can anybody help me out of this please?

Comment: Try to change architecture  to ARM64 only.

Comment: Hi Adrain Zhu, Thanks for the reply. I already tried this solution putting ARM64 only in the architecture, unfortunately it did not helped me.I also tried following solution <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\iPhone\ReleaseTemp</IntermediateOutputPath> Still have the same issue.